# Non-existent AdSense account is preventing me from signing up

Tags: google-adsense

I tried applying for an AdSense account using my gmail account but it was denied for being a duplicate of my old hotmail account. I must have signed up for it years ago, but never got around to using it. The email instructed me to sign in to my AdSense account with my hotmail address and add my gmail address to it.

The problem is that my hotmail account is a backup address to my gmail account, so if I try to log in with my hotmail account, it logs me into my gmail account. I deleted the hotmail account from my gmail account and tried to do an AdSense password reset with my hotmail email address but it says there's no account associated with that email...

I've spent hours going through the "Help" documentation and the closet thing I've been able to find is a request to review a denied application stating that you've never owned the email tied to the other account (which isn't true, it is my old email address.) Another form about issues logging in to your account requires my publisher id, which I obviously can't find since I can't log in.

Any ideas where I can go/what I can do next, or how to contact AdSense when none of their forms apply to me?

Comment: How Google continues to offer what I can only describe as a fragmented and haphazard solution for AdSense users is baffling - in the case of an AdWords account, I've found that the easiest solution was to create a new Google account for it (and then [forward all mail](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en) from the new account to my existing one).

Comment: Something flagged my gmail as being a duplicate of my old hotmail account (full name? address? no idea.) For AdSense I'd have to use my real name and address with a new google account in order to receive payments, so I'd assume they'd just flag that new one as a duplicate as well. This is all for a personal site so I don't have a company name/address to register under either.

Comment: Sounds like you'll just have to [contact AdSense support](https://www.google.com/adsense/contact) with whichever option is closest to the one you're encountering - it may take attempts on several different reasons before a human sees it, but keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

to easily contact adsense join there +adsense community in google plus and wait for there hangout....usually it occurs about once every weeek,there you can address your questions and be assured to get effective answers.
As to your question the only solution is to contact adsense just as i have mentioned above,or you can just create a new google account(delete the cookies and change ip address),get anew physicall address a new website or use the you tube way to get a new adsense account.
just as atip there are sites which provide you with a new adsense account ,just contact for

Comment: Google + is no more :o(